# Unity: Make public static Object assignable in Inspector

Tags: unity-game-engine

So, I have a Cinemachine Virtual Camera, that I need to assign in the Inspector but the problem is it's a *public static* one, so it's not shown in the Inspector. I tried to set the Inspector to Debug, but it's still not showing up.
I need to have it public *and* static because I need to access it from another script.

As you probably know, it didn't work making it only public, because then it's not accessible in the other script. I've tried with and without *[SerializeField]*, still the same result.

**Are there other methodes to make it accessible throught other scripts and how can I solve my Problem?**

Edit: I'm currently reviewing my questions and didn't know what the problem in this one even was. It's poorly written so I don't even know what was going on. I assume it was just a mistake because I was trying to acces the camera in a way that is not possible.

Comment: Do you have only a single instance of the object you are trying the access the value of?

Comment: " it didn't work making it only public, because then it's not accessible in the other script" that is not correct. A public variable is accessible from other script

Comment: `static` fields are not serialized .. fullstop. There is nothing you can change about that ..

Comment: @rusyBucketBay that is, in my case, not true. I've testet it with my Object and an Float value, both are not accessible from other scripts, if not static. I read a lot about it but somehow, it won't work for me.

Comment: @TheCrazy that makes no sense .. this is `c#` .. if something is `public` and your type accessible then you can access these public members via the instance of your type ... without you posting any source code of what you tried this is hard to answer though ... but rustyBucetBay is right and what you state is not correct

Comment: @derHugo I recorded myself while I typed in the given stuff and it didn't work. The Link is here: [MediaFire](https://www.mediafire.com/file/q0olahaj005inds/2022-01-03_18-00-39.mkv)  Maybe I did something wrong, and if you dedect it, I would appreciate it if you tell me what it was. Btw I'm sorry for the lag but OBS wasn't recording it better.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using FindObjectOfType() if you only have one camera in your level in order to reference it on awake and make it easier for you like

```cs
public static CinemachineVirtualCamera Cam;

private void Awake()
{
    Cam = FindObjectOfType(CinemachineVirtualCamera);
}
```

If you REALLY want to make static fields available to change in the inspector you might want to look into singletons and custom inspectors but I am not familiar enough with those to give you advice.

Answer (score 0):

if you make your class a singleton (i.e. do instance=this in awake), you can then do:

```
public static myField {get { return instance._myfield;}}
```